Significant Lag in Pose Mode
I use the same .blend file in two different Blender versions.
When I go to pose mode in Blender 4.0, it works very well, but now that I'm in Blender 4.1.1, the pose mode is very rough to move.
Has anyone else experienced the same problem?
